# Time Complexity of factorial

Tags: c, time-complexity

I have a number n, let's say n = 5. I've calculated n! like this:

1*2*3*4*5 = 1*2*3*20 = 1*2*60 = 1*120 = 120;

```
int factorial(int y){
    int z1 = 0;
    if (y != 0) goto L1;
    goto L7;
L1: z1 = equals(y);
    z1 = z1 - 1;
    if (z1 != 0) goto L5;
    goto L7;
L5: y = multiplication(y, z1);
L2: z1 = z1 - 1;
    if (z1 != 0) goto L3;
    goto E;
L3: y = multiplication(y, z1);
    z1 = z1 - 1;
    if (z1 != 0) goto L3;
    goto E;
E:  return y;
L7: return 1;
}
```

What is it's time complexity? Thank you.

Comment: Why... why didn't you just use a loop? (and the time complexity is linear, assuming `multiplication` and `equals` are O(1))

Comment: @Rizier123 Perhaps it's translated from disassembled code? That'd account for some of the weird label names too.

Comment: @duskwuff: Looking at the branches, I think you're right - translated from disassembled code that was generated for a CPU where forward branches are statically predicted as taken.

Answer (score 2):

Linear. Your obfuscating use of labels and `goto` can be directly translated into:

```
int factorial(int y){
    int z1 = 0;
    if (y == 0) return 1;

    z1 = equals(y);
    z1 = z1 - 1;
    if (z1 == 0) return 1;

    y = multiplication(y, z1);
    z1 = z1 - 1;
    if (z1 == 0) return y;

    do
    {
        y = multiplication(y, z1);
        z1 = z1 - 1;
    } while (z1 != 0)

    return y;
}
```

That `while` loop will execute `y - 2` times, which is linear in the value of `y`. Thus the runtime of the function is linear.

But I think this linear code is much simpler:

```
int factorial(int y) {
    // factorial(0) and factorial(1) are just 1
    if (y < 2) return 1;

    // Now just calculate y * (y - 1) * (y - 2) * ... * 4 * 3 * 2
    int f = y;
    while (--y > 1)
    {
        f *= y;
    }

    return f;
}
```

Comment: Note: For 32-bit (signed) integer results, a lookup table would be tiny and O(1).

Answer (score 1):

```
int factorial(int n){
    if(n==1 || n==0)
       return 1;
    return n*(factorial(n-1));
```

}

This implementation has T(n)=O(n). I think that also your implementation has the same complexity because the "do while" cycle is done n times.

Comment: This doesn't handle `factorial(0)`.